# Unix sed read from starting pattern till end of file

Tags: unix, sed

I'm trying to read a file from starting pattern till EOF. 
In below example read from 02/19/19 till EOF. However few lines are missed out. Not sure what is the cause.

```
sed -n -e '/\*\*\* 02\/19\/19/,//p' Myfile
```

Comment: It [seems to work](https://ideone.com/Pduoma).

Comment: Can you share your input file content

Comment: Try `sed -n -e '/\*\*\* 02.19.19/,$ p'`

Answer (score 0):

> However few lines are missed out. Not sure what is the cause.

Your shown command prints the lines from one `*** 02/19/19` to the next `*** 02/19/19`. That's because you specified `//` for the second address, where:

> The empty regular expression ‘//’ repeats the last regular expression match …

To get the lines *from 02/19/19 till EOF*, do as Walter A suggested and specify `$` for the end address, e. g.

```
sed -n -e '/*\*\* 02\/19\/19/,$p' Myfile
```